# R - parApply cannot evaluate function/find arguments with optim or optimx

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to maximize a function I created for every row in a data frame. It works fine when I do it with apply, but it doesn't work when I go to pApply. I can't understand why.

HERE IS THE FUNCTION (estimates the semivariance):

```
VB04 <- function(x) {
  #the argument is a vector of 2 parameters, the first is x, the second lambda

  ####I first define the function little f
  ff <- function(z) {
  ifelse (z <= x[2]*strike, return(x[1]), return(x[1]*(strike - z)/(strike*(1-x[2]))))
  }
  ####I then estimate the expected payoff of the contract
  require(pracma)
  require(np)
  profit <- quadgk(function(y) {
    #estimate the density
    #Here since I have estimated the weather index overall, I will look at the entire distribution
    density.pt <- npudens(bws = npudensbw(dat = as.data.frame(data.stations$weather_ind[
    which(data.stations$census_fips == census & data.stations$year < year_ext)]), 
                                      ckertype="epanechnikov", ckerorder=4), 
                      tdat = as.data.frame(data.stations$weather_ind[
                        which(data.stations$year < year_ext)]), 
                      edat = as.data.frame(y)) 
  #return the value of the expected profit
  return(ff(y)*density.pt$dens)
}, a = 0, b = strike)

##I now create a function that estimates the max
#I do this county by county, to get the best contract in each case.
#Only the density is estimated in common.
#first element of the max argument
max.arg <- sapply(-data.stations$yield[which(data.stations$census_fips == census 
                                               & data.stations$year < year_ext)] - 
                 sapply(data.stations$weather_ind[which(data.stations$census_fips == census 
                                                        & data.stations$year < year_ext)], ff), 
               function(x) x + yield_avg + profit[[1]])
#add a second column of zeroes
max.arg <- cbind(max.arg, 0)
#Take the max
max.arg <- apply(max.arg, 1, max)
#Return the final value, the sum of squares
return(sum(max.arg^2))
}
```

I want to apply it to each row of a data frame. Here are the first rows:

```
test[1:10,]
   census_fips yield_avg   strike
1        17143  161.8571 161.8571
2        17201  139.4286 139.4286
3        18003  147.4857 147.4857
4        18103  150.1571 150.1571
5        18105  137.8000 137.8000
6        18157  157.8714 157.8714
7        18163  149.5857 149.5857
8        19013  168.4286 168.4286
9        19033  163.9286 163.9286
10       19045  161.2286 161.2286
```

The optimization within parApply goes like this:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3) # My computer has 4 cores
registerDoParallel(cl)

clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("VB04"))

tempres <- parApply(cl=cl, X=test, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {
  strike <- x[3] #prepare the parameters
  yield_avg <- x[2]
  census <- x[1]
  require(optimx)
  minopt <- optimx(par=c(1,0.5), fn = VB04, lower=c(0,0), 
               upper=c(Inf,1), method="L-BFGS-B")
  return(cbind(minopt$fvalues[[1]],minopt$par[[1]])
})
```

With optimx I get the error: "Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters"
The optimization works fine when done for any row. It also works with apply.
When I try with optim instead of optimx, I get a different error: "object 'strike' not found"

I would really appreciate any help. I am not sure if the problem is that the parameters are not passed on (even though they are defined inside parApply), or something else. I can't find how to fix it.

Thanks,

EDIT:
Forgot to put the code for calling the clusters and for passing the function to the clusters. I have added it above

Comment: your question must contain only necessary details. Try framing short and concise question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in your code is that variables such as "strike", "yield_avg" and "census" are not in the scope of `VB04`, since they are local variables in the worker function.  You could fix that by defining `VB04` inside that function, also.  That will solve the scoping problem, and you also won't have to export `VB04`.

Here's a ridiculously stripped down version of your code that demonstrates this:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
test <- matrix(1:4, 2)
tempres <- parApply(cl, test, 1, function(x) {
  VB04 <- function() {
    strike * yield_avg
  }
  strike <- x[1]
  yield_avg <- x[2]
  VB04()
})
```

`optim` and `optimx` provide a way to pass additional arguments to the function, which may be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to using passing arguments in optimx directly before seeing your answer. Since I have many elements to go through, it seems like a faster way.